# to wear a jeans / jeans / a pair of jeans? which one is right?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number

I think "*to wear a pair of jeans*" is the correct formal saying but I see many people use "*to wear jeans*" & "*to wear a jeans*".

So, **to wear a jeans / jeans / a pair of jeans**? *which one is right*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jeans is a plural noun like pants/trousers.

So you cannot say I wear a jeans.  Instead, you usually say I wear jeans, though you can also say "I wear a pair of jeans".

Comment: if you search "**wear a jeans**" in Google, it will come out 70K results. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wear+a+jeans%22&oq=%22wear+a+jeans%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.759j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Tom Grammatically correct and often used don't mean the same thing. Also, try googling "wear jeans" and "wear a pair of jeans" and compare those numbers.

Comment: googling "wear a pair of jeans"  & my question comes up to the top of the result list

Comment: @Tom your quoted link is full of completely different statements in form "wear a jeans shirt" "wear a jeans jacket" etc - which are actaully grammatically correct, as there the article refers to "shirt" or "jacket", not "jeans".

Comment: @Tom a lot of the hits for your Google search are using Jeans as a synonym for denim, the fabric jeans are made from, rather than in the sense of a pair of jeans.